# Check MySQL query history with date and time

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is it possible to display all query executed in specific database with date and time?

I've tried

```
cat ~/.mysql_history
```

but it won't show when the query executed.

Answer (score 1):

A `general_log`, not enabled by default will record all queries against a database server. If only modification statements are needed you may be able to look at the binary log (if enabled) with `mysqlbinlog`.